# Bandwidth of a signal

Tags: signal, bandwidth, fourier

I have found that the convolution of two rect(f) functions (f=frequency) gives a triangular pulse of width 2 centred at 0 Hz. Can anyone tell me what the bandwidth of this pulse is? Is it F or 2F?

My professor wrote the bandwidth of a rect pulse (centred between -B and B) as B. Should it also be 2B?

It would be very helpful if you solved my doubt. (I have just started my analog and digital communications course).

What will the bandwidth be if the figure is right shifted such that the whole spectrum lies to the right of the origin? (Will it be 2 in this case?)

[image: Triangular pulse]

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  We don't give answers to homework problems, but if you show how you tried to solve it or your reasoning and where you got stuck or have doubts, you will likely get some hints.

Comment: The question was to find the bandwidth of the signal x(t) = sinc^2(t). I took its fourier transform and then convoluted the two rect pulses (graphical convolution) to get a value of (1+f) for 0<f<-1 and a value of (1-f) for 0<f<1. This is how I got the triangular pulse.

Comment: Prof is correct and ought to be 99% of the time

Comment: So, is the bandwidth of the figure I have shown 1 instead of 2Hz?

Comment: Ignore your doubt to understand why -B is the same as +B around 0 and always will be until you shift it from 0

Comment: @Tony Stewart So, if the spectrum is symmetric about the origin, the bandwidth will always be half the total width of the spectrum?

Comment: No but 0+/-B is just BW=B, yet for 1000+/-B, BW=2B  the difference between signals inside +B and -B is due to phase difference

Comment: @Tony Stewart What if instead of the pulse we either had a truncated sine or a cosine wave located between -B and +B. In this case, would the odd and even properties affect the bandwidth?

Comment: U are asking to make a half sine by multiply f * a pulse of known spectrum. So if you multiply in time domain , analyze f domain with what you know

Comment: No, I am asking whether the bandwidth will change if we had some spectrum which looks like an odd function centred at 0 and confined to -B and +B.(forget the figure that I posted)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a real time domain signal is analysed, there is always a half power mirror image of the half power positive frequency components in the origin of the frequency domain (SNR is unaffected because noise is also half power); well the real frequency components of the real time domain signal are an exact mirror image, but the imaginary frequency components of the real time domain signal are conjugated, so it's a conjugate reflection.

The point is, in a real signal, the negative side of the frequency domain is a mathematical figment derivable from the positive side, and therefore the bandwidth only concerns the positive frequency domain, and therefore the baseband bandwidth is B. If it were modulated up to a higher frequency, the passband bandwidth would be 2B, so long as it weren't modulated with SSB, where it would be B.

Only real signals can be transmitted – complex signals are transmitted as real signals using in phase and in quadrature complements. The complex baseband bandwidth of the signal is 2B.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending your valuable time in explaining the concept to me.

Answer (score 1):

### 2B or not 2B ... that is the?

Regardless of the shape of a 2B symmetrical +/-B spectrum on some carrier f centre   , if you shift  it down to 0="Baseband" the resulting BW is Only B, not 2B.(mirror image)

- consider it redundant spectrum -B=+B  which is why SSB was used for many analog channels like TV (but complex SSB notch filter on IF/ so not practical for other phase-distortion reasons to apply to all forms of communication)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.